# iOS >> Setting UIWindow in AppDelegate When Using Multiple Storyboards

Tags: ios, storyboard, idioms, appdelegate, info-plist

I wish to create an app with multiple storyboards to support iPhone5, iPhone4 (and below) and iPad screens.

I did the following:

1. I created 3 storyboards, one per each setting.
2. I cleared the "main storyboard" field in the project interface.
3. I cleared the "Main storyboard file base name" field in the app info.plist file.
4. I entered the following code to the AppDelegate "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method:

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {        

       UIStoryboard* appStoryboard = nil;

       if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) 
       {
           if (IS_IPHONE_5) //a macro capturing the screen size
           {
               appStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone5" bundle:nil];
           }
           else 
           {
               appStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone4" bundle:nil];
           }
       }
       else if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
       {
           appStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
       }
       UIViewController* viewController = [appStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
       [self.window setRootViewController:viewController];
       [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
       return YES;
   }
   ```

The application is running and not crashing, but I get a black screen.

What am I missing / doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't initialize the `window`.

Just add

`self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];`